# An Example for using AJAX calls to the controller method using JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to learn AJAX,JSON,JQUERY for using it in ASP.NET mvc.I want a simple example where an ajax call is made to the controller.The controller has a JSON data.An example like

```html
First Name :
Age :
Submit
```

It takes name,age and a submit button which can implement ajax.How do I do this using JSON data.It would be great if someone can explain me with the example I have provided above.

This is how the ajax call should be :

```html
$.ajax({
url:
data:
datatype:
});
```

Comment: Are you asking how to send data with ajax?

Comment: @rva.raghav, I wrote answer why did you delete question))))))))))))))

Comment: Check the question again.I have undeleted it @ElvinMammadov

Answer (score 0):

php exemple :

```
 <?php

if(isset($_POST)){

     $f_panne=$_POST['f_panne'];
     $p=$_POST['produit'];

   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=reparation', 'root', '');

      $req2 = $bdd->prepare('select  count(*) as nbre  from modele_produit Join panne_produit ON  modele_produit.id_modele=panne_produit.id_produit
         join type_panne ON panne_produit.id_panne=type_panne.code_type_panne
       join famille_panne ON type_panne.code_panne=famille_panne.code_panne where famille_panne.nom_panne=? and modele_produit.nom_modele= ?');

       $req2->execute(array($f_panne,$p));
       $response["nombre_panne"] = array();

     while(  $donnees2 = $req2->fetch()){
      $type = array();
        $type ['nbre']=$donnees2['nbre'];
        array_push($response["nombre_panne"], $type);
    }

     print  json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

in jquery :

```
  $.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"traitement/panne/calculer_nombre_famille_panne.php",
   data:{f_panne:f_panne,produit:produit},
   success:function(data){
   var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
   jQuery.each(obj["nombre_panne"], function(index, value) {


  // console.log(value.nbre);

  })

 }
});
```

Comment: I dont want php.A simple controller method.

Comment: i show you how you can use json with ajax when you encode your results in json , so you can replace php with asp

Comment: Can you give me a simple example with text box and button ?